# Issue generating a certificate signing request

Tags: java, windows, certificate, windows-server-2012

Hi I am trying to create a certificate request for HTTPS for a JAVA app. I have successfully created the tomcat.keystore and I am now trying to create certificate signing request but I get the below error.

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ôC:\cm_certreq.csrö (The
>   filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

I am running the following command as an admin:

> keytool -certreq -keyalg “RSA” -alias cm -file
>   “C:\Temp\cm_certreq.csr” -keystore
>   "C:\Users\Myaccount\Appdata\Roaming\Conf\tomcat.keystore"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess it's your quotes that is of some kind of wierd format by the look of it. Might be due to some encoding-issues in your IDE/tooling?

Try the following instead and it should work:

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg "RSA" -alias cm -file "C:\Temp\cm_certreq.csr" -keystore "C:\Users\Myaccount\Appdata\Roaming\Conf\tomcat.keystore"
```